# What is this the name of Android library made by google?

Tags: android, material-design

I've been searching for the past hour for this library name part of material design, it's made by google and had 10k+ stars on github but I can't for the life of me remember the name of it.

I tried finding it in

https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui

but it wasnt there.

[image]

you past a list of objects and connects it with a viewholder

Comment: Are you looking for [chips](https://material.io/components/chips/android#using-chips)?

Comment: if I remember correctly I had to add the dependency manually. But this will do, Thanks!!!
will be deleting question in 5 mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this:
https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Also there is the Flow feature in ConstraintLayout lib to achieve what you want

Comment: YES THAT IS IT I tried searching + picking my brain for an hour to remember the name of it that I last used about 1 year ago

Comment: it wont let me close the question unless you delete your answer.... haha

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE Instead of deleting it just accept his answer.